# How to invoke base-class method from second-level inherited class?

Tags: java, super

Let's say I have a base class called `Vehicle`, and another class called `Car` that extends it.  Finally I have a class `Luxury` that extends `Car`.

I know I can use the keyword `super` to invoke a base-class method.  How do I invoke a method of the `Vehicle` class from `Luxury`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin mechanism for this.  You have to create a helper method in the first subclass.

```
public class A {
    public void myMethod() { ... }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void myMethod() {
        // something
    }

    protected void myMethodA() {
        super.myMethod();
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    public void myMethod() {
        myMethodA();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works .. and If may I, in term of following best practice, when do you advice me to create helper methods ?

Comment: I would do it only as needed, and even then sparingly.  This kind of pattern breaks Liskov substitution principle since you should expect that a subclass of a class will behave the same as the class itself.  Needing this capability usually means something is misarchitected, but it can be a useful workaround until you have time to refactor.